# Prove a sequence is a $O(1/n^3)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

> let $p$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and $(u_n)$ a sequence such that : $\sqrt{u_n} = \pi n + O(\frac{1}{n})$ when $n \to \infty$.
>
> Now I need to prove that the sequence :
> $$v_n = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{u_n})}{\sqrt{u_n}} + \frac{1}{u_n}\int_0^1\sin(\sqrt{u_n}(1-x))p(x)\sin(\sqrt{u_n}x) \mathrm{d}x$$
>
> is an $O(\frac{1}{n^3})$ when $n \to \infty$

I am must say that I don't understand how $v_n$ can be a $O(\frac{1}{n^3})$. I mean we have : $\sin(\sqrt{u_n}) = (-1)^k \sin(O(1/n))$ thus when $n$ goes to infinty $\mid \sin(\sqrt{u_n}) \mid \sim O(1/n)$. Thus we get that : $\mid \frac{\sin(\sqrt{u_n})}{\sqrt{u_n}} \mid  \sim O(\frac{1}{n^2})$. So here already I don't get the cube...

Thank you !

Comment: The sequence you wish to prove has a few things I'm not clear about. First, what is $p(x)$? Second, it uses $v_n$ in $2$ places, but doesn't define what $v_0$ is or how each value is related. Please clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: Is it intended that $v_n$ is given only by a *quadratic* equation?

Comment: @JohnOmielan $p$ is defined at the beginning, it's just a a continuous function (it can be whatever continunous function), and I only what $v_n$ is at $\infty$

Comment: You cannot prove that $v_n=O(n^{-3})$ because it is not true.

Comment: @uniquesolution yes thank you, so It's just a $O(n^{-2})$ right ?

Comment: @bonjoufhajl I appreciate the fast response, and sorry for missing that $p$ was defined initially.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes it is since the sequence $(u_n)$ is closely related with a differential equation with parameters and $v_n$ is an aproximation of a DE of order $2$.

Comment: @bonjoufahjl - If you take $p(x)=0$ it is $O(n^{-1})$. And if you take $p(x)=1$ you get something else, which does not look like $O(n^{-2})$, because it has a term of the form $\frac{\cos v_n}{v_n}$. It looks like the problem is ill posed, something is missing.

Comment: @uniquesolution Oups you are right, I copied the wrong expression... sorry It's correct now

Comment: I tried letting $p(x)$ being the constant $1$ and $\sqrt {u_n} =\pi n+1/n$ and did not get $O(1/n^3).$ For constant $ p$, the integral can be evaluated using $ (\cos (A-B) -\cos (A+B))/2=\sin A \sin B$ with  $A=(1-x)\sqrt {u_n}$ and $B=x\sqrt {u_n}.$.... I dk your source or context, but $O(1/n^3)$ may be a typo.